# Getting same emails multiple times to same user

Tags: php

I am trying to post the email to the user when the admin creates a new event. The email is triggering, but the student is getting the same emails multiple time. I used for each in the code. Any help Appreciated.

```
   $this->properties->id = $DB->insert_record('event', $this->properties);
   $tooo = $DB->get_record('role', array('shortname' => 'student'));
   $too =  $DB->get_records('role_assignments', array('roleid' => $tooo->id));
   $pageNos = array();
   foreach($too as $new)
   {
      $t = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $new->userid));
       // if(!in_array($t,$pageNos)){
      $body = "event has been posted by {$USER->username} : {$content} on student assignment "; 
      email_to_user($t,$USER,'event Notification ','The text of the message',$body);
   }
```

Comment: Because you are sending emails in the foreach loop

Comment: `$tooo` and `$too` make me shudder. Surely there are better names these variables could hold?

Comment: get the distinct student ids

Comment: @RopAliMunshi If we want to post event to the multiple student means we need to put it in the fior each only right.. I am totally confusing.. If you have idea means can you please efit the code..

Comment: If anyone knows, how to edit the code means, please edit the code.

Comment: we are only guessing a bit because we can't see your data, and we don't know what the functions this code calls are doing, either. You need to debug it and see whether the same users are appearing multiple times in your query results. That would be an obvious reason why they might get the same email more than once.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
$this->properties->id = $DB->insert_record('event', $this->properties);
$tooo = $DB->get_record('role', array('shortname' => 'student'));
$too =  $DB->get_records('role_assignments', array('roleid' => $tooo->id));
$pageNos = array();
foreach($too as $new)
{
   if(!in_array($new->userid,$pageNos))
   {
     $t = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $new->userid));
     $body = "event has been posted by {$USER->username} : {$content} on student assignment "; 
     email_to_user($t,$USER,'event Notification ','The text of the message',$body);
     $pageNos[] = $new->userid;
   }
}
```

Comment: what have you changed, and why? A code dump is not much use without explanation, really. It's not easy to learn from it

Comment: @ADyson If you are going to learn from this question - I can only remain silent.

Comment: @IVOGELOV lol cryptic but not especially informative. TBH I wasn't thinking of me specifically, I can see what your intent was, but it would be much _easier_ and quicker for everyone to understand your answer if you add a simple description. That's far more likely to get you upvotes (instead of the opposite).

Comment: @ADyson It depends on your viewpoint. Some people will share your opinion (that the question is totally OK but the answer is terrible) while others will see through the veil. Note that OP did not complain.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I don't think the question is particularly great either, tbh. You'll note I already commented on that precise topic in the comments under the question. Maybe OP is happy to blindly copy and paste code without necessarily knowing what it does, and hope that it works without any unintended consequences, but I wouldn't be happy with that - it's a bit too close to cargo-cult programming for my liking. Or maybe they understood it immediately - but then if that was the case, you may start to wonder why they couldn't have written it themselves...

Comment: @ADyson This kind of people come to SO because people like me and you answer to their questions. They do not know how to ask properly - but this does not bother them. We are volunteering here to teach them - but they do not want a lesson, they simply need someone to solve their problem for free. If you look at the OP' code you'll see the required statement is already there although commented and using the wrong variable. So he was unable to explain the problem but immediately recognized the solution.